# Calling a class from Windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm learning Windows Forms and I'm stuck when working with Windows Forms and Classes. I want to make a form in which a user can enter the temperature in Farenheit then click a "convert" button and this will take the input value to a "convert" class where it gets converted to Celsius then have both Farenheit and Celsius displayed on a message box.

I have designed the form and I know how to create the class. What I don't know is how to take the input value (farenheit) from the form to a class then calling the converted value from the form and display it in a message box.

I'm a beginner in C# so I'd appreciate your comprehension and beginner-like answers.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create method

```
public class Convertor
{
 public datatype FarenheitToCelsius(String value)
 {
  datatype celsius;
  ...conversion logic   
  return celsius;
 }
}
```

Then you need to call method of class

```
public class form1
{
   public void button_click(arguments...)
   {
       Convertor c = new Convertor();
       MessageBox.Show(c.FarenheitToCelsius(textbox1.text));
   }
}
```

**Note**: this is just a partial example

Comment: yes, i know how to create a method inside a class and the conversion logic but what I'm asking is how to display in this case the celsius result in a MessageBox.

Comment: thank you...I see what you are doing here however, when I do it i get an error in the MessageBox line saying "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property. How do I correct that?

Comment: @Oskar  - just remove method as static and create the instace of converter class to access the method will remove error

Comment: If i wanted to add an error message in case the user doesn't enter any values, how can i do that?  I assume if/else I tried it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare two public [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in the class one is `setFarenheit` and another one is `getConvertedheit`, now you can call the class and can create properties as follows.The following two properties are inside the class

```
public string setFarenheit { set; }
public string getConvertedheit { get; set; }
```

and assign the converted heit value to the getConvertedheit property in your class.

```
getConvertedheit = heitConvertedintoCelcius;//your converted celcius heit temp inside the class.
```

And in the Form class you can call it like follows if they exist in same namespace.

```
HeitConvertingClass hcc = new HeitConvertingClass();
hcc.setFarenheit=Userinput(the datatype is your choice may be int or float);
MessageBox.Show(hcc.getCovertedheit.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's two ways that this can go: databinding or accessing the values via the TEXT property of the text box.

The second is the easier to show in this scenario, so let's go with that.

You'd have this code in your CONVERT button's Click Event handler (and this is assuming that your conversion class has a CONVERT method that takes in a the farenheit temp as a string and then returns the string you want to display).

```
convert c = new convert();
myConversionString as string = c.ConvertForDisplay(MyTextBoxName.Text);
MessageBox.Show(myConversionString);
```

That's the BASIC way to get that value into your class, and the end result back into the UI.